# laravel 8 get error 503 without exception message

Tags: laravel, exception, laravel-artisan, http-status-code-503, phpdebugbar

My project worked properly while today get 503 without exception message.
This fix after run `php artisan cache:clear` command for one time but after refresh page then get 503 again.

I tried these:
`cleared bootstrap/cache files`
`delete vendor and composer update --no-script`
and some solutions but not solve my problem

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

[image]

Comment: Most likely your server was down. It can also be that you made a request to another server which was down/unavailable for some reason, it can be a service you are using

Answer (score 0):

finally i found the problem and solve it.
the problem was with the maintenance middleware

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if(Cache::has("setting")){
        $setting = Cache::get("setting");
        if($setting->updating_site == 1){
            if(Auth::check() == false){
                abort(503);
            }
            if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role != "admin") {
                abort(503);
            }
        }
    }

    return $next($request);

}
```

in the middleware check value from setting for maintenance mode and if is true return 503

Answer (score -1):

> **php artisan up** please try this command

I researched a little and solved the problem. The problem is not in laravel installation. The problem is on the server. Restart all services from the WHM interface. The error is resolved.

Comment: @farshid abdi I hope you got your correct sloution

Comment: tried this but no chnage !